# Is there a repository of modern Amateur Radio transceiver schematics?

Tags: transceiver

I am looking for a repository (SVN ect) of modern Amateur transceiver schematics.
Most of the designs you can find with a simple Google search either use tubes, or now obsolete and hard to find components.

Comment: Maybe you are using the wrong search terms. If you don't want tubes, try "transistor". In any case, the question is too broad. I'm sure there is such a repository. Probably hundreds of them. We could list them here, but that's what search engines are for.

Comment: Now you've got me looking at the KX3 schematics, thinking about building my own...

Comment: Phil, my Google Fu is strong. When I search for transceivers particularly 2m ones I get stuff like this from '93 http://www.intio.or.jp/jf10zl/144fm.htm

I'm after a central repo for ham schematics. It appears there is none.

Answer (score 0):

I did a few searches and I came across this:

http://www.cqham.ru/sch_eng.html

It is not a comprehensive listing, but I does cover a number of known modern brands and radios, such as those made by Icom, Alinco, Albrecht, Kenwood and Yaesu, for both HAM & CB radios.

If you require a schematic for a specific radio, I would recommend trying out a term such as:

`yaesu "ft-60" schematics`

Replacing the brand and model shown with your own.